# Deciding locants of double bonds vs. other substituents

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

After having decided that the keto-group is the highest priority, this is a ketone. However, does the double bond become C2, or does the amino become C3?

In locant placement, do we prioritize **double bonds over substituents**, or other **substituents over double bonds**? (Or is it just a matter of having the smallest starting number?)

[image]

5-aminocyclohex-2-enone

3-aminocyclohex-5-enone

Comment: Double bonds are preferred over substituents according to IUPAC nomenclature, so the first name should be correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the current version of [*Nomenclature of Organic Chemistry – IUPAC Recommendations and Preferred Names 2013 (Blue Book)*](http://dx.doi.org/10.1039/9781849733069) while numbering the parent chain, an unsaturation is preferred over a substitutent.

> P-14.4 Numbering
>
> When several structural features appear in cyclic and acylic compounds, low locants are assigned  to them in the following decreasing order of seniority.
>
> .. (a) fixed numbering of a ring or ring system;
> .. (b) heteroatoms in chains and in rings and ring systems;
> .. (c) indicated hydrogen;
> .. **(d) principal characteristic groups and free valences (suffixes);**
> .. (e) added hydrogen;
> .. **(f) saturation/unsaturation (hydro/dehydro prefixes and ‘ene’ and ‘yne’ endings);**
> .. (g) detachable alphabetized prefixes, all considered together in a series of increasing numerical  order;
> .. **(h) lowest locants for the substituent cited first as a prefix in the name;**
> ..

As per the preference order the ketone will get the priority first as it is the principal characteristic group. Thus the name will end in an -one.

Now as the unsaturation is preferred over a substituent the numbering will be done in such a way that the double bond gets the lower number.

Thus the preferred IUPAC name of this molecule would be **(5*S*)-5-aminocyclohex-2-en-1-one**.